# How to count the items which have same value using SQL?

Tags: sql

These are my data:

equipment re_date   remark

AHU# 1 2/1/2014 bag filter dirty

AHU# 1 2/3/2014     bag filter dirty

AHU# 1 2/4/2014     bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/5/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/8/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/10/2014  bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/11/2014  bag filter dirty

AHU# 1  2/12/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 1  2/13/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 1  2/15/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 1  2/18/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/19/2014  bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/20/2014  bag filter dirty

AHU# 1   2/23/2014  bag filter dirty

AHU# 14  2/1/2014   unit off

AHU# 14  2/3/2014   unit off

AHU# 14  2/4/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/5/2014    unit off

AHU# 14 2/6/2014    unit off

AHU# 14 2/8/2014    unit off

AHU# 14 2/10/2014   return fan off

AHU# 14 2/11/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/12/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/13/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/15/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/18/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/19/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/20/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/23/2014   unit off

AHU# 14 2/26/2014   unit off

AHU# 17 2/3/2014    bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/5/2014    bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/8/2014    bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/10/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/11/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/12/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/13/2014   bag filter dirty

AHU# 17 2/15/2014   bag filter dirty

can you help me please to get the count of items have same value in first column.

Comment: What are your column names?

Comment: the column name is equipment

Answer (score 5):

```
select col1, count(col1) from table1 group by col1
```